# MySQL IN return only one rows while JOIN query return desired result?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables , structures are given below

#### table_incident

```
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| id(PK)    | incident_display_id | account_id | customized_fields_id  |
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| 47614     |      33             |        394 | 1285,1286,1287,1288   |
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

#### table_customized_fields_data

```
+------+------------+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| id   | account_id | field_id(FK) | incident_id(FK) | value      |
+------+------------+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1285 |        394 |       49     |   47614         | Nikon 5MP  |
| 1286 |        394 |       50     |   47614         | CDMA       |
| 1287 |        394 |       51     |   47614         | Yes        |
| 1288 |        394 |       84     |   47614         | 9317001007 |
+------+------------+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

#### table_customized_fields

```
+----+------------+------------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| id | account_id | field_type | label               | name | field_lable |
+----+------------+------------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| 49 |        394 | text_field | Camera              |      |             |
| 50 |        394 | checkbox   | Cellphone           |      | CDMA, GSM   |
| 51 |        394 | radio      | Sunglasses          |      | Yes, No     |
| 52 |        394 | textarea   | Credit Card         |      | 5           |
| 83 |        394 | radio      | Cowboy Hat          |      | Yes,No      |
| 84 |        394 | text_field | Emergency Contact # |      |             |
+----+------------+------------+---------------------+------+-------------+
```

Now i want to select only those label and  regarding value of that lable which exists in `table_incident`,

i fired below query

```
SELECT ti.id IncID,tcf.id labelID,tcfd.id dataID,tcf.label, tcfd.value
FROM  table_customized_fields_data tcfd  
INNER JOIN table_incident ti  ON (ti.id = tcfd.incident_id)
INNER JOIN table_customized_fields tcf ON (tcf.id = tcfd.field_id)
WHERE tcfd.id IN (ti.customized_fields_id)
AND ti.id=47614


+-------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| IncID | labelID | dataID | label  | value     |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 47614 |      49 |   1285 | Camera | Nikon 5MP |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

but only one row is returned, will you all please tell me what wrong i m doing though each subquery working perfect individually.

**Note:**  although this query retruns the desired data:

```
SELECT tcf.id AS labelID,tcf.label,tcfd.id AS dataID, tcfd.value
FROM table_customized_fields_data tcfd 
JOIN table_customized_fields tcf ON tcf.id=tcfd.field_id
JOIN table_incident ti ON ti.id=tcfd.incident_id
WHERE ti.id=47614
```

but i think there must be some optimized way, please share your idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your second query IS the optimized way. Just make sure you have an index on `table_customized_fields_data.incident_id`.

Also I think you have misunderstood how [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) works, quote from the manual:

> **expr IN (value,...)**
>
> Returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else returns 0...

so your

```
tcfd.id IN (ti.customized_fields_id)
```

is equivalent to:

```
tcfd.id = ti.customized_fields_id
```

Comment: if i want all data then what shoud i use??

Comment: @diEcho I don't know what you mean by "all data", Isn't your second query returning the "desired data"?

Comment: please read the question again... i written 2'nd query is working perfect but why IN is not working??

Comment: all data means  4 rows. which operator i have to use??

Answer (score 1):

`ti.customized_fields_id` is a string, not an array. It's not matching, but you're getting one row because it's a left join and it's mysql.

What you want is something like this:

```
SELECT ti.id IncID,tcf.id labelID,tcfd.id dataID,tcf.label, tcfd.value
FROM  table_customized_fields_data tcfd  
INNER JOIN table_incident ti  ON ti.id = tcfd.incident_id 
    AND concat(',', customized_fields_id, ',') like concat('%,', tcfd.id, ',%')
INNER JOIN table_customized_fields tcf ON tcf.id = tcfd.field_id
WHERE ti.id=47614
```

which says `tcfd.id` is in the string `customized_fields_id` when delimited by commas

Comment: @Bohemian..but using `%` can be dangerous, there are 1000 of data which intial starts with same number

Comment: it Returns last 3 rows only. can't we change the datatype using `CAST` before `IN`